# Pointing multiple routes to same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my route structure

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
     <Route path='/view/:title' component={Home}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

As you can see I am pointing both of my routes to my Home component. In my Home component, I have three child components inside Home component's render method.

Lets say, `<Header />, <Sidebar /> and <Content />.`

What I want to achieve is that I want to call my  component's render() method again and update the  area only.

I am already preventing unwanted update of `<Header /> and <Sidebar />` using `shouldComponentUpdate`. But I am not able to figure a way out to call the render() method of `<Home />` component when the route to the component has called.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Here is my view layout:

[image]

Comment: what version of React are you using?

Comment: If you can put a unique "ref" on the different Home components it should force react to rerender it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a unique ref to the Home component in order to get a re-render for different routes:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/'>
        <Home ref="root" />
     </Route>
     <Route path='/view/:title'>
        <Home ref="view" />
     <Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

But better yet, you should put the routing inside your Home Component:

```
const App = () =>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <SideBar />
    <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
         <Route path='/view/:title' component={ViewPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ref clue. I have added a layout diagram of what I am trying to achieve. Can you check it again and let me know I am looking for at the right path or not.?

Comment: I am getting an error says 'Stateless function components cannot have refs'

Comment: Make sure your Home component extends React.Component so that you can add refs. I also updated my answer to give an alternative (better) solution.